# Why am I getting an integer error from SAS date and how do I correct it?

Tags: sas

Can anyone see what I have incorrect on this date macro? I want sysdate - 7 days, I want to go back one week for the date.

```
"WEEK OVER WEEK COMPARISON SUMMARY" @&sysdate -7 Format=MMDDYYS10.;
    
  1 line "WEEK OVER WEEK COMPARISON SUMMARY" @10JUN22 -7 Format=MMDDYYS10.;
                                                              _
                                                              22
ERROR 22-322: Expecting an integer constant.
```

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example. It is unclear what this code does or where it would be within a macro. Is it in open code? Is it in a data step? Is it in a `put` or `%put` statement? The code itself is not valid SAS syntax on its own.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `&sysdate`?  That's the date that the session started, so if your session has been opened for some time it may not be the current day.  If you are after the current day formatted nicely, a more accurate way to do it is `%sysfunc(date(), MMDDYYS10.)`

Answer (score 1):

In a macro context date arithmetic can be done with `%sysfunc(intnx...`  %sysfunc has a parameter for specifying the format of the computed result when it is returned to the macro system as source.

So, your macro implementation *might* need to be changed to

```
"WEEK OVER WEEK COMPARISON SUMMARY - %sysfunc(intnx(day,"&sysdate"d,-7), mmddyys10.)";
```